# typescript string and numbered indices

Tags: typescript

In JS, `array[0]` and `array['0']` return the same value. Similarly `Object.hasOwn(array, '0')` and `Object.hasOwn(array, 0)` both return `true`.

> How to stipulate a type, that allows both number and string indices to an array?

If I use `keyof Array<T>` it returns error message "Cannot assign to 'length' because it is a read-only property." And if I use `keyof Uint8Array`, the typed array I'm using, additional "read-only" errors are returned.

If I use `string | number` the error is "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'"

Of course I can just set it to `string` and then `Number()` but recently learning ts so wondering if there is another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would declare it like this:

```
let index: number | `${number}`
```

`index` can now be any number or any string which can be converted to a number.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDMBTA7jAqgSzCgA4BBJOATwAoBKAKHsQQG0AGAXSaXa+ZYBEbAXx4C4AI2AjG9ACYZgAG0QYYSjLEIKAHgC50AVwC2EjMgA+MAAYASAN5gTZhAF9rjbRh2oYbel4+aEICAWC6vuJSodysgRxAA)

Comment: Out of curiosity do you know if I also could have used regex?

Comment: It's not possible to use a regex at type level, only at runtime.